# A word for special type of person

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to find a word that describes an individual who votes in this way; check the word below `ballot` from *longman*
[image]

what do we call this person? a **secret voter**? a **voter**?
Is there more specific word other **voter**?

Comment: A 'secret voter' implies that the voter does not want it to be known that they have taken part in an election or ballot at all. The 'secret' part of 'secret vote' refers to *which option* the voter chooses. Most ballots are secret, but sometimes they are conducted by a [**show of hands**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Show+of+Hands).

Comment: The person is a **voter**.